# Android Camera and Video Filters

Tags: android, filter, ffmpeg, camera

I am developing camera app.
this app uses camera filter made of video(mp4.file).
filter made of video file.
I used merge camera recording and filter video with ffmpeg but this is bad (very slow)
also I used blend bitmap and camera with opengles (I got realtime bitmap with MediaMetadataRetriever getFrameattime)but it is bad too(slow,low quality)

In other words, I want to get the merged file(camera and video overlay)
please help me TT